# Software centers for Ubuntu that have package upload services - apart from Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, upload, paid-applications

Are there any popular software centers for Ubuntu that have package upload services? Not counting the Ubuntu Software Center.

Also, are there any that support paid-for applications?

Comment: try this one?? http://www.appgrid.org/

Comment: @RonnieDroid doesn't seem to have package upload services...

Comment: No, NOT the USC - big difference here